# POST <input> file as binary/octet-stream Content-Type using Axios

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, axios

My plan is to upload a file received from an input tag, to an S3 bucket.
I need to manage a way to pass that file of type `[Object file]` into a supported type for the header of my API `"Content-Type: "binary/octet-stream"`. But I've tried using `Buffer.from()`, `.toString("base64")` but none of these made any changes.

This is the API POST request:

```
export async function sendToS3(uploadURL, file) {
  let request = {
    method: "PUT",
    url: uploadURL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "binary/octet-stream",
    },
    data: file
  };

  const response = await axios(request);
  return response.data;
};
```

And this is how the received file looks, which I need to send to S3:

```
File {
  name: "filename.jpg",
  lastModified: "1652758134934",
  size: "64058",
  type: "image/jpeg",
  webkitRelativePath: "folderName/filename.jpg"
}
```

Comment: In case this might help someone; It ended up working by changing the backend enctype to `multipart/form-data`, and worked as a charm. Otherwise I was getting close to a solution by converting the File to binary with the FileReader() and readAsBinaryString(file) method.